# How to get time ago from a firestore timestamp (firebase)?

Tags: angular, firebase, date, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to get the "time ago" from a date I have stored in a firestore database.

I've tried two packages that are supposed to do that but I can't get it to work with the firestore timestamp and honestly I can't believe it is as hard as it's been to get this.

Whats the easiest way to get the "time ago" that updates by itself?

I managed to get just the complete date form the firestore's timestamp, just not the time ago version of it.

Comment: Using moment.js: `moment(firestoreTimestamp.toDate()).fromNow()`

Answer (score 6):

If you store the date in Firestore as a `timestamp` in the document (e.g. with [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#.serverTimestamp)), the following Javascript code will give you the elapsed time since the `storedTimestamp`'s date, in milliseconds:

```
    var db = firebase.firestore();

    var docRef = db.collection('yourCollection').doc('yourDocId');

    docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            var storedDate = new Date(doc.data().storedTimestamp);
            var nowDate = new Date();
            var elapsedTime = (nowDate.getTime() - storedDate.getTime());
            console.log(elapsedTime);

        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
```

---

You could also use the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library, as follows, for example to get the difference in days.

```
    docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            var storedDate = moment(doc.data().storedTimestamp);
            var nowDate = moment();
            //get the difference in days, for example
            console.log(nowDate.diff(storedDate, 'days'))

        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
```

Comment: new Date(doc.data().storedTimestamp) didn't worked for me. new Date(doc.data().storedTimestamp.toDate()) worked well.